# Pepper plants dropping fruit when they get to be the size of a pea

Tags: diagnosis

We have planted peppers in "earth boxes".  They look great, blossom freely and set fruit.  Then the fruit falls off.  ??

Comment: Pepper is a difficult plant (in my opinion). Could you describe what soil do you have, how much sun and how (quantity, frequency) do you water them?

Comment: Also where you are and whether you;re growing in or outdoors - a photo might be useful too.